# Что происходит с выполняющимся потоком (TThread) при уничтожении формы?

Tags: многопоточность, lazarus, delphi

Пишу многопоточное приложение. Есть форма. При нажатии пользователем кнопки на форме создаётся поток, в котором происходит поиск файлов на всех локальных дисках.

Необходимо ли "вручную" осуществлять `Terminate` и `Free` потока при `destroy` формы? Например, если пользователь при выполнении потока закроет окно программы или завершит процесс. Или же это необязательно и при уничтожении формы ресурсы потока освободятся "сами"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, нужно обязательно освободить ресурсы.
Если FreeOnTerminate := True, то достаточно сделать

```
FThread.Terminate
FThread.WaitFor;
```

Если FreeOnTerminate := False, то нужно сделать еще и Free:

```
FThread.Terminate
FThread.WaitFor;
FThread.Free;
```

Но для того, чтобы Terminate отрабатывал нужно в процедуре Execute следить за переменной Terminated:

```
procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Если `FreeOnTerminate := True`, то так просто сделать нельзя, ведь к моменту обращения, поток может уже завершиться и освободиться - получаем доступ к освобожденному объекту с соответствующими эффектами.